# Not set Java version for specific folder and all subfolders

Tags: java, sdkman

Linux Mint 20
Java 8, 11.
SDKMAN: 5.12.14

Current Java version = 11

I have folder `MyProject` with 45 subfolders:

```
MyProject
- mySubfolder1
- mySubfolder2
-...
- mySubfolder45
```

I want to set specific Java version to 8 to folder `MyProject` and all its 45 subfolders.

I create  file `.sdkmanrc` in folder `MyProject` with content:

```
# Enable auto-env through the sdkman_auto_env config
# Add key=value pairs of SDKs to use below
java=jdk1.8.0_202
```

And when I open folder `MyProject` and use this command:

```
java -version
```

I got `java = 1.8`.

Nice. It works fine.

However, when I open any subfolder, for example `mySubfolder2`, the Java version is 11.

Is it possible to set Java 8 for folder `MyProject` and **all** its subfolders?

I don't want to create file `.sdkmanrc` in all subfolders

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is not possible. There is a feature request to support this in future. https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/1102

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this on SDKMAN 5.15.0 with Java 11 & 17, Mac OS 12.5.

Are you sure you set `sdkman_auto_env=true` in `sdk config` (which opens the config file in your default editor)?

Comment: I have the same issue. SDKMAN 5.17.0 with Java 11 and 17, Mac OS 13. 
`sdkman_auto_env=true` my default is java 11, for the project I have set java 17. In the subfolders I get java 11 in contrast to the wanted behavior to have the same sdk for all subfolders.